# Does anybody know of a non-api, locally persisted database solution for angular?

Tags: angular, database, sqlite-net

I have spent the last week searching and trying numerous wrappers for indexeddb ony to find out it is not a great idea if data persistence is paramount.  Looking at sqlite, but there seems to be no support for it in angular 11 and all the examples i find are 1+ year old or more and target really old versions of angular and use apis for storage requests.  I'm about researched out at this point and this is my last attempt to find something useable.  The data could be 1,000s of records.

Comment: I know jstore: https://jsstore.net/ As you say, it's a bit old and, personally, I don't like so much because it's return Promises and not Observables, but work well

Comment: does your data persist between sessions?  What browser are you using?

Comment: Is a "wrapper" of indexedDb, I think that all modern browsers can use: NOTE there're anothers "warppers" of indexedDb, I put jsstore because it's the only I used and has a Angular integration more or less confortable